# Моя любимая тема про выделение памяти, на этот раз new

Tags: c++, указатели, new

Глупые вопросики,так что не закидывайте вилами,мб для кого-то это мега понятна,а кто-то я.
Поделю 2 вопроса блоками.

**Блок1**

Предположим,я выделил память,что я могу сюда записать и как могу разделить,а так же как могу использовать? *Вопрос риторический,скорей сам себе для рассуждения*

```
char *ptr =new char(20); //Или же char *ptr = malloc(05)
```

Я понимаю так: `*ptr` у меня получает значение 20 указателей на тип `char*`,в каждом из которых 1 байт т.е. 8 бит нулей/единиц,но из-за особенности типа в каждом свой символ. Я могу записывать в каждый байт что-то,а могу записать значение которое будет занимать не больше выделенного.

Т.е.

1. хочу 5 слов по 4 байта(символа)`ptr[0]='aaaa';ptr[4]='aaaa')(и так ещё 3 раза,предположим что 'aaaa'заняли 4 байта(1 буква - 1 байт),для наглядности)` итого 20 байт-пожалуйста.
2. Хочу 20 букв(символов) `ptr[0]='a';ptr[1]='a')(и так ещё 18 раз,предположим что 'a'заняла 1 байт(1буква-1байт),для наглядности)`в сумме так же 20 байт-без проблем.

Так же, **тут мои мысли,не больше** я  могу записать ну например,хочу `ptr[0]=(int)123`и мы занимаем `int`ом 4 байта (1число 4 байта т.к. `int`) и всего могу только 5 циферок записать на тип `int` и т.д. Смысл того что пихаю ногой и `int` значение, 5 `int`ов по 4 байта в сумме 20 байт выделенной памяти.

**Блок2**

И ещё момент,выделяем точно так же память,но.

```
char *ptr =new char(23) //Или же char *ptr = malloc(23);
ptr[0]='aaaa';
char **ptrLine= (char**)ptr;
ptrLine[0]=(char*)ptr[0];
```

И тут у меня небольшая трудность в понимании.
Предположим дальше я занял немного памяти `ptr[0]='aaaa'` на 4 байта,ради примера(4 буквы 'a'). И я получаю адрес на 0вой занятый 4мя байтами элемент.

И вдруг я захотел сделать что-то такое `ptrLine[0]=(char*)ptr[0]`.

И у меня вытекает 2 вопроса из моих блоков.

1. **Блок1** Правильно ли я понял и расписал свои мысли?
2. **Блок2** Что я сделал написав код `ptrLine[0]=(char*)ptr[0]`? что мне это дало? (Не обязательно давать мне сложные примеры если вдруг они есть,мне достаточно описать словами,деревенским языком)

P.s. Про `delete` не забыл,прост это пример, чисто для моего понимания.

Comment: Не уверен, что правильно вас понял. Вы думаете, что здесь `ptr[0]='aaaa'` или здесь `ptr[0]=(int)123` будет записано по четыре байта? Т.е. будут записаны некоторые значения в `ptr[0]`, `ptr[1]`, `ptr[2]` и `ptr[3]`?

Comment: @wololo  `ptr[0]='aaaa'` 4буквый `a` каждая по 1 байту. Грубо говоря 4 буквы-4  байта.  \\  `ptr[0]=(int)123` в данном примере размер `int` 4 байта за 1 циферку ,тоже для примера.

Comment: Так будет после выполнения `ptr[0]=(int)123;`, с вашей точки зрения, что-нибудь записано в `ptr[1]` или нет?

Comment: @wololo я пытаюсь рассуждать что: Если я заполню `ptr[0]=(int)123;ptr[1]=(int)123;ptr[2]=(int)123;ptr[3]=(int)123;ptr[4]=(int)123;` не смотря на то что `ptr` типа `char`,то это будет рабочий вариант,а главное как раз в притык к выделенным 20байтам памяти

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 char *ptr =new char(20);
```

здесь выделяется память под один байт (под один char). Сюрприз:)

Поэтому, писать куда то далее (например, `ptr[1] = 3;`) уже плохо - запись за пределы выделенной памяти. Наверно хотелось написать так

```
char *ptr =new char[20];
```

> ,но из-за особенности типа в каждом свой символ

нет, Вы так и не осознали факта, что байт - это байт, а то как Вы его интерпретируете, это другое дело.

```
ptr[0]=(int)123
```

так как слева у нас char, то будет произведено приведение типа. И никаких "4 байт" никто не будет занимать. То есть, в первом байте будет записано 123 (да, char обычно знаковый, а 123 < 128).

```
char *ptr =new char(23) //Или же char *ptr = malloc(23); - уже выяснили, что здесь ошибка
ptr[0]='aaaa'; // а это просто ptr[0] = 1633771873;, по факту запишется 97
char **ptrLine= (char**)ptr; // а зачем приводить тип к тому, чем он не является?
ptrLine[0]=(char*)ptr[0]; // а точно хотите понимать, как именно это может отстрелить ногу ?
```

*тут были рассуждения о этом коде, но я их решил удалить, оставив просто немножко ниже*

в последней строке ptr[0] - это char, а Вы его к указателю преобразовываете. В целом, код бессмысленный и даже не стоит его обсуждать. Компилятор выдает такое кол-во предупреждений, что дурно.

Если компилятор на Ваш код выдает предупреждения, не нужно пытаться понять, что делает этот код, скорее всего он просто плохо написан и его надо написать корректно.

Comment: .-. Окей,допустим я что-то понял. Но ведь верно ли я рассуждаю что хочу число не 123 а 1231, то  `ptr[0]=(int)1231` будет записано в `ptr[0]`, `ptr[1]` (ну точнее оно будет в `ptr[0]`,но займёт дополнительные биты у `ptr[1]`) ?

Comment: И ещё `Вы так и не осознали факта`  Я понимаю что это байт, от -128 до 126 и заполняется символами из-за Вашими же словами `это просто представление этих байтов` т.е. простыми словами: особенность этого типа char. Просто не понимаю что не так-то теперь Х)

Comment: `ptr[0]=(int)1231` - нет, не будет оно трогать ptr[1]. Байт - это просто байт, это обычно восемь бит (может быть и по другому). Будет это от 0 до 255 или -128 до 127 или символ - все зависит от того, как мы решили интерпретировать эти биты (что бы компилятору и подсказываем, указывая тип).

Comment: Это значит что мне нужно выделять отдельную область памяти,но теперь только под `short` ? ну т.е. если я хочу записывать число 1231,то мне тогда нужно использовать как раз таки `short *ptr=new short[2]; ptr[0]=(int)1231`что бы попало в границу и не было переполнения. Теперь верно? Х)

Comment: если нужно записать два байта - да, выделяйте так и пишите. Будет писать по два байта, но следующий элемент (в третий байт) оно не затронет

Comment: И пока не забыл Х) Сори за мучения,но уж оч хочется быть просветлённым) `char *ptr =new char(20);` я понимал что [20] даст мне массив из 20 элементов,но в `malloc(20)` с помощью круглых скобок можно так же сделать,обратиться как к массиву. Тогда что даёт это `char *ptr =new char(20);` просто выделил байт и сразу же записал в него значение 20 ?

Comment: `new char(20)` - выделить char и записать сразу 20. `new char[20]` - выделить массив на 20 char. Просто new - это не функция.

Comment: Спасибо, что уже не в первой теме помогаете разобраться Х)

Comment: а есть кто то, кому эта тема не нравится, минусует ходит все

Comment: да,чел с ником user и цифры какие-то,написал в пред. посте что ему моя тема не нравится и мол название не соответствует.,хотя в инструкции все было соблюдено. Я ему закинул репорт,его сообщеньку и удалили,а тут хз кто,наверное он же.